# How did the Hyuga clan come to be?

Tags: naruto

So as we have seen in the Hagoromo filler:

> Hagoromo didn't inherit the Byakugan and could not pas it over so a clan (Like Uchiha with Sharingan) Can be born. and we see that Hamura has the Byakugan, but he leaves and goes to the moon, and we see in "The Last: Naruto The Movie" That he formed a clan on the moon and there was a whole civilization there, but before he takes off for the moon there was no mention of his romantic life and no indication that he took someone with him.

So when was the Hyuga clan formed? did Hamura came back and took someone and formed a clan? or is this just a plot hole?

Comment: I think it's just something we have to speculate by ourselves...

Answer (score 2):

*`Before going to the moon, Hamura's bloodline on Earth continued, which eventually would become the Hyūga clan and the Byakugan was also passed down to them.`*

There is no mention of Hamura's love life or his children, but at this point the only logical explanation would be that his lineage continued through someone (who's never shown in the anime) and thus formed the Hyuga.

Also, there is a direct descendant of Hamura Otsutsuki mentioned in "Naruto: The Last" movie belonging to the same clan, Toneri Otsutsuki not exactly someone who is responsible for creating the Hyuga clan.

Here's more about Hamura Otsutsuki, his lineage and abilities: [Hamura Tsutsuki wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hamura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)